# "be given offters of help" or "be given willingness of help"

Tags: differences, language-formation

In this sentence, " a woman is often given more___of help with her broken-down car when she is dressed attractively than when she is dressed less appealingly."
The answer is "offers", but why not willingness? Is it because that the "willingness" is not written in a plural form?

Answer (score 1):

"Willingness" is a feeling, not a property that can be given away, it is inherent to the possesor.  You could communicate THAT you possess a feeling of willingness to someone else, but you can't transfer your state to them.  The "-ness" suffix indicates is a state of the person who has it.

But an "offer" is by definition a message you give to someone else to propose a gift or trade.